# "Operation could destabilize the runtime" Message when using RDLC

Tags: asp.net, crash, rdlc

When running an RDLC, I get the following message displayed inside the report frame:

```
Failed to load host assembly. Operation could destabilize the runtime.
```

Does anyone have any idea which assembly is being referred to. Better still, where is there a seam I can check to figure out which assemblies are being loaded and which are not. I don't think this is an issue with the RDLC assemblies themselves because:

1. I've installed the report viewer locally.
2. Other RDLC's work (or at least load).

I'm truly baffled on this one. Many thanks for whatever help is offered.

Answer (score 1):

can you show us how do u the datasource of report?
please put your code here
usually this error occurs when you system try to serialize an uknown object
adding xmlincludeattribute to class(the class of report data source) may solve your problem

Comment: Wow, haven't thought of this one in a while. I'll take a look, but the project this relates to isn't under active development. Giving you the upvote anyway as this is the most plausible answer I've gotten anywhere.

Comment: Thx,i had such problem when i wanted to serialize a class that i created in runtime ...